# Golang Query limit 1 have no rows.next() value

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm using golang to query to database, the query is dynamic it's base on parameter what we get.
but I have unexpected result. when I use query with limit 1.

```
rows, err := dbUserMaster.Query("SELECT id FROM tables OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1")
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err,"")
}
if rows.Next() == false {
        return nil, errors.New("Data Not Exist")
}
for rows.Next() {
 function()
}
```

I check on debuger the value of next is nil, but got lastcols. and also I check on postgres, got  the value.

Comment: Are you checking the returned `err` value? If not, why not!? Are you saying that when limit is *not* set to 1, everything works as it should? Can you show what `function()` does? What do you mean by "value of next is nil"? `rows.Next()` is a method, and it itself cannot return `nil`, it either returns `true` or `false`. I don't see any other "next" in your code.

Comment: not really sure, but it's look like when I use limit i always got -1 result.  I mean not for my metode, but rows.next(). 
yes, I check value of err but it's nil.

Comment: I see you're trying to implement paging, so I would suggest declaring [CURSOR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) and use its [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) functionality.
You will save a lot of time solving issues later, e.g. https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/paginators-the-story-about-voluntary-pain/

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

It's because I use

```
if rows.Next() == false {
        return nil, errors.New("Data Not Exist")
}
```

before use :

```
for rows.Next() {
 function()
}
```

when I remove first one, I got correct result.